# Contracting a symmetric tensor product with a covector

Tags: tensors, symmetric-matrices

What I actually want to ask is about a problem of specific form, which I could not put in the title as I'm not certain on any short name for such problems.

For given a rank-2 tensor $K^{\mu\nu}$ and a unit vector $q^\mu$, a projection problem, to find a vector $\alpha^\mu$ which satisfies
$$(K^{\mu\nu}-q^\mu\alpha^\nu)q_\mu=0$$
can be easily solved by contraction
$$K^{\mu\nu}q_\mu = (q^\mu\alpha^\nu)q_\mu = \alpha^\nu$$
$$\alpha^\nu = K^{\mu\nu}q_\mu.$$

In a similar sense, I want to solve the projection problem for the symmetric tensor $K^{(\mu\nu)}$, where the remainder term becomes appropriately symmetric to preserve the symmetry, so that
$$(K^{(\mu\nu)}-q^{(\mu}\alpha^{\nu)})q_\mu = 0.$$
For me, only restricting the space to the symmetric seems to make the problem unable to approach.
For some specific simple cases, direct calculations give the answer, such as for the Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^2$,
$$\alpha^\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
K^{22}(q_1)(q_2)^2-2K^{11}(q_1)(q_2)^2-2K^{(12)}(q_2)^3-K^{11}(q_1)^3 \\
K^{11}(q_1)^2(q_2)-2K^{22}(q_1)^2(q_2)-2K^{(12)}(q_1)^3-K^{22}(q_2)^3
\end{pmatrix}_\mu. $$
What I predict to be needed to solve the problem in general, is the contraction of the symmetric product $q^{(\mu}\alpha^{\nu)}$ by the convector $q_\mu$ in a viable form (as $(q^\mu\alpha^\nu)q_\mu$ is simply $\alpha^\nu$), where the title comes from.

What would be the form if there is one, or am I taking the route with a dead end?
What is your view on the problem?